# how do i remove empty elements from an Array

Tags: groovy

I am trying to remove empty elements i.e. double quotes from array but i am not sure how to iterate through json array. Below is my json

```
{
  "body": {
   "newId":"value1"
  },
  "header": {
    "appId": "someVal",
    "pricingSchedule": [
      "price1",
      "price2",
      "price3",
      "",
      "",
      ""
    ]
  },
  "trail": {

    "pageSize": "50"
  }
}
```

what i want to do is in the `header` i want to iterate through `pricingSchedule` array and remove empty elements and if there are no elements in array then i want to simply keep empty array rather then removing it.

Below is my attempted code -

```
def request = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())

def newRequest = evaluate(request.inspect())


request.body.each { entry ->
    if (entry.getValue().equals('') || entry.getValue().equals([''])) {
        newRequest.body.remove(entry.getKey())
    }
}


request.header.each{ entry ->

//  String key=entry.getKey().equals("pricingSchedule")


    entry.getKey().equals("pricingSchedule").each{ entry1 ->

        log.info(entry1) //This does not print anything and gives me error

        }

}


def arguments = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()
sampler.setArguments(arguments)
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(newRequest).toPrettyString(), '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the empty elements from `pricingSchedule`, just do:

```
request.header.pricingSchedule = request.header.pricingSchedule.findAll()
```

This will remove any elements that are null, or the empty string

Comment: This one liner did perfectly for me